# Executing second controller's "this" in first controller through angular service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two controllers and a service, i am executing first controller "self/this" in the second controller. I wanted to know is this an antipattern or are there any chances of memory leak?

SelfService -- this service stores "this" of controllers in selfContainer Object.

The setSelf method takes two parameters -- name of the this/self controller and this/self itself. -- it stores them as key value pair in selfContainer Object.

The executeWithSelf method also takes two parameters -- name of the this/self and a callback. the callback is executed with the this/self as parameter.

```
angular.module('app')
.factory('SelfService', function () {
  var selfContainer = {};
  function setSelf (selfname , self) {
    selfContainer[selfname] = self;
  }
  function executeWithSelf (selfname, callback) {
    callback(selfContainer[selfname]);
  }
return {
    setSelf: setSelf,
    executeWithSelf: executeWithSelf
  };
});
```

FirstController

```
angular.module('app').controller('FirstController', function(QueryService){
  var self = this;
  self.counter = 0;
  QueryService.setSelf('FirstController', self);
})
```

Second Controller

```
angular.module('app').controller('SecondController', function(QueryService){
  var self = this;
//execute QueryService.executeWithSelf on any event and only after first controller has loaded
  QueryService.executeWithSelf('FirstController', function(firstcontrollerself){
    firstcontrollerself.counter++;
  });
})
```

Comment: Not sure if what you are doing is a problem but you can achieve communication between controllers through other means - scope.emit and scope.broadcast or an event aggregator service

Comment: @Banners thanks for your feedback, what is was doing was a basic event aggregator service

Comment: also known as a pub/sub service - here's an example - https://github.com/phiggins42/bloody-jquery-plugins/blob/master/pubsub.js the idea is you register for topics calling subscribe with a callback and then you get notified when someone publishes to that topic. In angular you can wrap in a factory and then inject into your controllers